# Not able to store value in variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to find percentage of two values from the database.
when I perform the calculation the variable is not storing the result. someone please tell me why it is happening.

```
private int GetPercentage(int re, int al)
{
    float k;
    if (al > 0)
    {
        k  = (float) (re / al) * 100;
    }
    else
    {
        k = 100;
    }
    if (k < 10)
    {
        float p = 100 - k;
        Label3.Visible = true;
        Label3.Text = "Customer has used more than " + p + "% of Allotted LPOs";
    }
    int l = 100 - (int)k;
    return l;
}
```

Comment: Where should it store the result? You're not returning the result anywhere.

Comment: just want to return the variable p. it didn't copy properly

Comment: re / al => you are doing integer division. It will always return 0 if re is less than al. Change your variable to decimal or float

Comment: `(float) (re / al) * 100` should probably be `((float)re / al) * 100`.

Comment: I have it in my code but the value p is not having the result. that is the issue

Comment: Which value do the parameters re and al contain?

Comment: integer values which I retrieved from database

Comment: Because the parameters are integer values you wont't be able to step into the second if. Because this calculation: (float)(re / al) * 100 always returns 0 or a value over 100. When al is higher than re you will receive 0, when re is higher, you will receive 100 or more. And the cast to float is useless, you never get a value with comma.

Comment: Please provide clear question, varible name where you can't store result, may be you can provide input parameters values of `re` and `al`, that people can understand your problem. How question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again you´re confused by integer-semantics. From maths we know that 1 / 3 is 0.33333333... However the same does not apply to programming, where an intereger (what 1 and 3 are) devided with another one **allways** results in another integer, whereby a float multiplied with another one **allways** results in a `float`.

Thus the following returns zero:

```
1 / 3
```

Thus you have to tell the compiler that you want **floating-point**-arithmetic, which can be achieved by casting one of the operators to `float` or by using float-literals. The following expression returns a correct float:

```
1f / 3
```

Alternativly you may also write `1.0 / 3` or `1 / 3f` or `1 / 3.0`.

So what you need in your code is this:

```
private int GetPercentage(int re, int al)
{
    float k;
    if (al > 0)
    {
        k  = ((float) re / al) * 100; // see here, you need to cast to float
    }
    else
    {
        k = 100;
    }
    if (k < 10)
    {
        float p = 100 - k;
        Label3.Visible = true;
        Label3.Text = "Customer has used more than " + p + "% of Allotted LPOs";
    }
    int l = 100 - (int)k;
    return l;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the variables k and l in the method GetPercentage. Because of that, they're not available somewhere else.
You can do the second if like this:

```
if (k < 10)
{
    Label3.Visible = true;
    Label3.Text = "Customer has used more than " + p + "% of Allotted LPOs";
    return (float)100 - k;
}
```

Comment: I am able to return the variable properly, the real problem is the variables am returning doesn't have the results.

Comment: The variable state at the end of function is re 3 
  al = 10,  
  k = 0, 
  l = 0, 
  p = 0  this is what I am confused about

Comment: If re is 3 and al 10, you won't get an result. Because this calculation: (float)(re / al) * 100 always returns 0 or a value over 100. When al is higher than re you will receive 0, when re is higher, you will receive 100 or more. And the cast to float is useless, you never get a value with comma. I think if the parameters are convertet to float, you will get the correct result.

Comment: Why converting to float? Makes no sense IMHO.

Comment: yes. that is the issue. thanks . I didn't notice the comment in by peeyush

Comment: @HimBromBeere I show you with an example: p1 = (int) 3, p2 = (int) 9, if you do the calculation p1 / p2, the result is zero. If they are float, you will get 0.33. And because he uses the result of the calculation again, he must do it with float. Because 0 is the wrong answer.

Comment: True, but you are not deviding an int with an int, but substracting a float (`k`) 
 from an int (`100`), which will **allways** return a float. No need to cast again.

Comment: Yes, thats right. Thank you for that. He cast was wrong at his code (float) re / al, then it will return an int. But if you cast it like you do, it will return an float ((float) re / al). Thank you!